# Can xargs evaluate $HOME?

Tags: linux, bash, xargs

When I type in

```
echo $HOME/Downloads | xargs cd
```

It correctly changes directory to $HOME/Downloads. Maybe that is because `echo` evaluates `$HOME` before piping to `xargs`.

However if I type

```
echo '$HOME/Downloads' | xargs cd
```

`$HOME/Downloads` is passed as it is to `xargs` and it fails to change directory. It gives an error:

> /usr/bin/cd: line 4: cd: $HOME/Downloads: No such file or directory

So my question is can `xargs` evaluate `$HOME`, if it can how.

Comment: That is a bash variable, so bash need to evaluate it.  When you put things in quotes, you are telling bash not to evaluate it.  How about [edit]ing the question to describe what you are trying to achieve (ie why you can't use the first option).

Comment: @Paul I understand that when I put it in quotes I'm passing the variable as it is (without evaluating) to `xargs`. My question is: can `xargs` work on bash variables. Apparently it cannot, at least the way I'm doing it. Is there any other way of making `xargs` evaluate bash variables.

Comment: No, only bash can.  So you need to use the first format.

Comment: If you would just provide more information we can probably find a solution that doesn't require this.  http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem

Comment: @Paul :D. No, I'm not trying to solve Y. I'm just curious if `xargs` can evaluate bash variables. Please write an answer based on your previous comment so that we can close this question.

Comment: Hah, ok cool.  I was encouraging you because I was curious what you were up to -  how you came to ask the question!

Comment: @Paul though it will be really nice if you could explain why it cannot evaluate bash variable. Bash as I know is a program which executes other small programs. If Bash has a variable, why can `xargs` which executes inside it have access to bash variable. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bash variables can only be evaluated by the bash shell.

When you `echo '$HOME/dir'` and pipe the results to another command, you are telling bash to not evaluate the variable and treat the parameter as a string.

xargs (and most other commands) don't have a concept of bash variables - they would need to invoke a bash shell to evaluate them.  For example:

```
echo '$HOME/dir' | xargs bash -c cd
```

This would invoke a bash shell which would evaluate the variable and cd into the correct director.  However upon completion, the shell would terminate and return control to the original shell (which would still be in the starting directory.

So it works, but probably not how you want it too.

Answer (score 1):

> Paul's explanation is correct. My reply in the following was written before Anurag Peshne kindly re-explained to me what he meant, see comments below. I am leaving my reply as it stands even though it is not relevant because it seems to me cowardly to hide my errors.

---

The expression which does **not** work as the original OP would like contains:

```
    echo '$HOME/Downloads'
```

that is, a shell variable inside single quotes, <kbd>''</kbd>. This is standard bash shell lingo for *do not evaluate the expression inside the single quotes*. In fact,

```
    $ echo '$HOME/Downloads'
      $HOME/Downloads
    $ echo "$HOME/Downloads"
      /home/myname/Downloads
```

Notice the difference between using single quotes, <kbd>''</kbd>, and double quotes, <kbd>" "</kbd>, which instead mean: do substitute variables.

In fact, the Bash manual has this to say about this difference:

> [3.1.2.2 Single Quotes](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Single-Quotes.html)
>
> Enclosing characters in single quotes (‘'’) preserves the literal value of each character within the quotes. A single quote may not occur between single quotes, even when preceded by a backslash.
>
> [3.1.2.3 Double Quotes](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Double-Quotes.html)
>
> Enclosing characters in double quotes (‘"’) preserves the literal value of all characters within the quotes, with the exception of ‘$’, ‘`’, ‘\’, and, when history expansion is enabled, ‘!’. The characters ‘$’ and ‘`’ retain their special meaning within double quotes (see Shell Expansions). The backslash retains its special meaning only when followed by one of the following characters: ‘$’, ‘`’, ‘"’, ‘\’, or newline. Within double quotes, backslashes that are followed by one of these characters are removed. Backslashes preceding characters without a special meaning are left unmodified. A double quote may be quoted within double quotes by preceding it with a backslash. If enabled, history expansion will be performed unless an ‘!’ appearing in double quotes is escaped using a backslash. The backslash preceding the ‘!’ is not removed.
>
> The special parameters ‘*’ and ‘@’ have special meaning when in double quotes (see Shell Parameter Expansion).

In short, the commands displayed by the OP work exactly as the Bash manual states, and this whole business is totally urelated to the behavior of *xargs*.

Comment: Yeah, somehow the quotes got lost in the first example so I fixed it.

Comment: What you have mentioned here is absolutely correct but I think you have misunderstood my question. I'm curious to know what happens after we pass '$HOME/Downloads' (without evaluating) to `xargs`. I found out that it cannot evaluate `$HOME`, I want to know if there is a way such that `xargs` can evaluate it.

Comment: @AnuragPeshne Thanks for clarifying, in fact  I had **not** understood your question.

Comment: It took me a while to understand your answer :D